# ZF2 + APC = fatal errors

Tags: zend-framework2, apc

I did a simple install of [APC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.cache.storage.adapter.html#the-apc-adapter) (no special configurations) and didn't integrate with code at all (letting it go default and making sure things work). I was super impressed to see my [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) times drop from 300ms to 50ms right after I enabled it! But then I noticed that actually, the server is crashing immediately. Here's the problem:

After I restart Apache, the first request works. Following the first request, I get a slew of errors in my error logs.

Some of these errors are:

```
Call to a member function getFieldValue() on a non-object in Zend/Http/PhpEnvironment/Request.php (zf2 lib)
```

Undefined Property:

```
Zend\\Http\\Headers::$h\x9b\xecv\xb9\x7f in Zend/Http/Headers.php
```

Is there some magic I'm missing? These seem like errors out of my control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended by the ZF community to use opcache instead of APC cache. This was enabled with the default installation requirements and everything worked.